# Unideal comment with NERD_Commenter,comment javascript embed html file

Tags: html, vim, comments, indentation

some javascript codes embedded in html as below:

commented with the vim plugin NERD_Commenter

```
<body>
    <script language="javascript">
        <!--alert("hello word");-->
        <!--alert("hello word");-->
        <!--alert("hello word");-->
        <!--alert("hello word");-->
    </script>
</body>
```

I'd like the inner javascript codes commented in a style below:

```
    <script language="javascript">
        //alert("hello word");
        //alert("hello word");
        //alert("hello word");
        //alert("hello word");

    </script>
```

How to deal with it? Or is there a better plugin for code commenting?

Comment: I don't know of a commenting plugin that supports mixed languages. I would file an issue here https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter/issues Supporting comments for mixed languages would be useful. Another example would be XSLT. Comments around the XSLT are <!-- -->, whereas comments inside the XPath statements used in XSLT are like this (: :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [tcomment.vim](http://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim). That's what I use and it supports some mixed language highlighting ([demo](http://vimsomnia.blogspot.com/2010/11/tcomment-vim-plugin.html)). For example you can use `gc<motion>` to comment text or `gcc` to comment a line and it will usually detect the language appropriately.